# r - add multiple markers to rMaps

Tags: r, rmaps

**Question**

How do you add multiple markers using [`rMaps`](https://github.com/ramnathv/rMaps)?

**Data**

```
coords <- structure(list(stop_id = 19841:19843, stop_name = c("Flagstaff Railway Station (Melbourne City)", 
"Melbourne Central Railway Station (Melbourne City)", "Parliament Railway Station (Melbourne City)"
), stop_lat = c(-37.8119813073807, -37.8099387667386, -37.8110540555305
), stop_lon = c(144.955653760429, 144.962593535096, 144.972910916416
)), .Names = c("stop_id", "stop_name", "stop_lat", "stop_lon"
), sorted = "stop_id", row.names = 17:19, class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

**Examples**

Using `library(rMaps)` I can create a map and add a single marker, as per the examples on Ramnath's github page:

```
library(rMaps)

l <- Leaflet$new()
l$setView(c(-37.8602828, 145.079616), zoom=11)
l$tileLayer(provider = "Acetate.terrain")

## add one marker:
l$marker(LatLng = c(-37.81198,144.9557))
```

But I can't figure out how to add multiple markers from the `coords` data frame, without writing a `l$marker` line for each one.

I've tried to use `GeoJSON` but I'm new to this so haven't got my head around it yet and must be doing something wrong.

```
# library(rgdal)
# coords.sp <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords[,.(stop_lon, stop_lat)], coords[,.(stop_id, stop_name)])
# writeOGR(obj=coords.sp, dsn='coords.geojson', layer='OGRGeoJSON', driver='GeoJSON')

# gj <- readOGR("./coords.geojson", layer="OGRGeoJSON")
# l$geoJson(gj)
# l$geoJson("./coords.geojson")
```

I'm happy to use `JSON/GeoJSON` if it's the way to go.

**Desired output**

I would like the result to be the same as if I used `library(leaflet)` to show multiple markers

```
library(leaflet)
leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles("Acetate.terrain") %>%
  setView(lat = -37.8602828, lng = 145.079616, zoom=11) %>%
  addMarkers(data=coords, lat=~stop_lat, lng=~stop_lon)
```

[image: marker_example]

**GeoJSON**

Here is the GeoJSON code that's produced from the `writeOGR` command, and I've validated it [at GeoJSONLint](http://geojsonlint.com/)

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",

"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "id": 1, "properties": { "stop_id": 19841, "stop_name": "Flagstaff Railway Station (Melbourne City)" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 144.955653760428987, -37.811981307380698 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "id": 2, "properties": { "stop_id": 19842, "stop_name": "Melbourne Central Railway Station (Melbourne City)" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 144.962593535096005, -37.809938766738597 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "id": 3, "properties": { "stop_id": 19843, "stop_name": "Parliament Railway Station (Melbourne City)" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 144.972910916415998, -37.811054055530498 ] } }
]}
```

Comment: Hm what about a loop in the veins of `apply(unname(coords[, c("stop_lat", "stop_lon")]), 1, l$marker)`?

Comment: @lukeA, good idea, but at the moment it's placed the markers in *slightly* the wrong place (but very close); I'll have a look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can make use of [`library(geojsonio)`](http://recology.info/2015/01/geojson-topojson-io/) to correctly read the GeoJSON file, and then use `l$geoJson` to load the markers onto the map

```
## create spatial object and save as GeoJSON
# library(rgdal)
coords.sp <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords[,.(stop_lon, stop_lat)], coords[,.(stop_id, stop_name)])
writeOGR(obj=coords.sp, dsn='coords.geojson', layer='OGRGeoJSON', driver='GeoJSON')

l <- Leaflet$new()
l$setView(c(-37.8602828, 145.079616), zoom=11)
l$tileLayer(provider = "Acetate.terrain")

## Read the GeoJSON data
library(geojsonio)
gj <- geojson_read("./coords.geojson")
l$geoJson(gj)
```

[image: markers plotted with geoJson]